# AttributeError: 'SpaceTextEditor' object has no attribute 'active_operator'

Tags: python, error, file-browser

I get this error when I try to run my script from the text editor. It is a simple exporter with some extra functions.

This code snippet is the culprit for the error:

```
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):
    sfile = context.space_data
    operator = sfile.active_operator

    return operator.bl_idname == 'TEST_OT_advanced_export'
```

`TEST_OT_advanced_export` is my `bl_idname`. After running I am constantly getting the following error in my system console:

> AttributeError: 'SpaceTextEditor' object has no attribute 'active_operator'

As far as I know, I need the poll function inside my class so that my defined custom attributes that appear in the File Browser do not appear when another function from Blender shows the File Browser.
My script works perfectly fine, but it is spamming the error into the system console.
How can I resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

Removing the poll function out of the class solves the problem and keeps the functionality that the custom attributes do not appear in File Browser not called by this script.

But you have to keep the poll functions in all custom panels that you want to appear in only your File Browser.

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests that the `context.space_data` object, which is of type `SpaceTextEditor`, does not have an attribute called `active_operator`. The `active_operator` attribute is likely specific to a different type of space data, such as `SpaceView3D`, which is used for 3D modeling and animation.

It's likely that the poll method in this scenario is intended to be used with a different type of operator or space data, and is not suitable for use with `SpaceTextEditor`. You should check the documentation or the source code of the operator or addon that defines this method to see if it is intended to be used in this way.

Comment: The thing is I wrote the operator myself and was trying to fix the problem that my custom attributes that I defined in my class, that appear in my File Browser while using my export function were appearing in other File Browsers when Blender shows my one

Comment: add a check for `sfile.type` prior to assigning `operator = sfile.active_operator` if sfile.type is not a file browser return false.

Comment: the problem is that sfile.type is always of type VIEW_3D when run through favorites menu, a custom panel or search bar or of type TEXT EDITOR and never the file browser